# Pausar ou Encerrar vídeo do youtube

Tags: jquery

Atualmente uso o seguinte script para pausar o vídeo do youtube:

HTML:

```
<span onClick="stopVideo();" class="wmg-close"></span>

<div id="player<?= $dAgenda['id'];?>"></div>
```

JavaScript dentro do Laço de repetição do PHP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
            var player;
              function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player<?= $dAgenda['id'];?>', {
                  height: '230',
                  width: '454',
                  videoId: '<?= $dAgenda['link'];?>',
                  events: {}
                });
            }
              function stopVideo() {
                player.stopVideo();
              }         
            </script>
```

Fora do Laço de repetição do PHP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
</script>
```

Conclusão:

O vídeo está aparecendo apenas para o último filme do laço de repetição do PHP!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Utilize a API JavaScript do próprio [YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=pt-br)

Inicie o vídeo e coloque ele na variável player (conforme o exemplo da própria API)

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: { }
    });
}
```

Depois apenas adicione ao clique do seu `span` o método para parar o vídeo

```
function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
}
```

Exemplo utilizando a API [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kdbgn2qt/1/)

Comment: Tem como fazer um exemplo aqui...não consegui achar esse exemplo na API do Youtube, obrigado!

Comment: Realizei essa dica que você passou, mas o vídeo só aparece para o último filme, que é o (WALL). Os outro não aparece o iframe!

Comment: Irei fazer um exemplo hoje a noite, pois aqui no trabalho o youtube é bloqueado, você poderia só atualizar o html para facilitar?

Comment: Editei lá a minha pergunta...

Comment: @user3081segue o exemplo http://jsfiddle.net/kdbgn2qt/

Comment: Usa essa versão, encontrei um bug na anterior http://jsfiddle.net/kdbgn2qt/1/